# Can't communicate my data between nodejs server and client with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i'm begining at socket.io and node js.
I'm trying to make a multiplayer "rock paper scissors" game.
Here is my server.js

```
var app = require('express')(),
server = require('http').createServer(app)
io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

function GameServer(){
this.p1 = ""
this.p2 = "";
this.choice1 = "";
this.choice2 = "";
this.countPlayer = 0;
}

GameServer.prototype = {
addPlayer: function(player){
    if(this.countPlayer < 1)
        this.p1 = player.name;
    else
        this.p2 = player.name;
},
addChoice: function(player){
    if(this.p1 == player.name)
        this.choice1 = player.choice;
    else if(this.p2 == player.name)
        this.choice2 = player.choice;
},
getData: function(data){
    //var gameData = {};
    if(this.p1 =="")
        this.p1 = data.p1;
    else if(this.p1 !="" && this.p2=="")
        this.p2 = data.p2;        
    if(this.choice1 =="")
        this.choice1 = data.choice1;
    else if(this.choice1 !="" && this.choice2=="")
        this.choice2 = data.choice2;
}
}

var game = new GameServer();

/* Connection events */
io.on('connection', function(client) {
client.on('ClientInfoGame', function(player){
    console.log('User '+player.name+' connected');
    console.log('he chose '+player.choice);
    game.getData(player);
});
console.log("on passe au emit")
client.emit('ServerInfoGame', {p1:game.p1,p2:game.p2,choice1:game.choice1,choice2:game.choice})
});

server.listen(8888);
```

and here is my index.html with my javascript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Super Chat temps réel !</title>
        <style>
            #zone_chat strong {
                color: white;
            background-color: black;
            padding: 2px;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <h1>JANKEN GAME</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="submit" id="r" value="Rock" />
        <input type="submit" id="p" value="Paper" />
        <input type="submit" id="s" value="Sissor" />
    </form>
    <h2 class="result"> Make a choice</h2> 
    <section id="zone_chat">
    </section>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    function player(nom,choix,socket){
        this.name=nom;
        this.choice = choix;
        this.opponentChoice=""
        this.socket=socket
    }
    player.prototype.sendDataToServer = function() {
        //we send data from client to server
        //var data = this;
        this.socket.emit("ClientInfoGame",{name:this.name,choice:this.choice});
    };
    player.prototype.getDataFromServer = function() {
        //we get data from server 
        this.socket.on("ServerInfoGame",function(dataFromServer){
            var data = dataFromServer;
            if(data.p1 == this.name)
                this.opponentChoice = data.choice2;
            else if (data.p2 == this.name)
                this.opponentChoice = data.choice1;
        })
    };
    player.prototype.winnerIs = function() {
        console.log("opponnent choice ..."+ this.opponentChoice)

        if(this.choice == "Rock" && this.opponentChoice == "Rock" || this.choice == "Paper" && this.opponentChoice == "Paper" || this.choice == "Sissor" && this.opponentChoice == "Sissor" )
            return "Draaaaww , try again";   
        else if(this.choice == "Rock" && this.opponentChoice == "Sissor" || this.choice == "Paper" && this.opponentChoice == "Rock" || this.choice == "Sissor" && this.opponentChoice == "Paper" )
            return " YOU WIIIIIINNN ";  
        else if(this.opponentChoice == "Rock" && this.choice == "Sissor" || this.opponentChoice == "Paper" && this.choice == "Rock" || this.opponentChoice == "Sissor" && this.choice == "Paper" )
            return " YOU LOOOOOOSE ";
    };
    function end(p){
        $('h1.result').empty(); 
        $('h1.result').text(p.winnerIs()).html();
    }

        var choice = "";
        $('#r').on('click', function(){choice = "Rock"; p.choice = choice;})
        $('#p').on('click', function(){choice = "Paper"; p.choice = choice;})
        $('#s').on('click', function(){choice = "Sissor"; p.choice = choice;})
        var pseudo = prompt('What's your name?');
        // Connexion à socket.io
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
        var p = new player(pseudo,choice,socket);
        //document.title = pseudo + ' - ' + document.title;
//            socket.emit('choice', choice)
        //socket.emit("infoPlayer",p)
        p.sendDataToServer();
        p.getDataFromServer();            
        end(p);
    </script>
</body>
```

On my client side (index.html) i create a player object with name and choice attributes (rock, paper or scissor).
when a player click on a button its change choice value and then its send a player object to the server.

On my server side, i get values from each clients, add it to my gameServer object and send it to all clients then client will apply game logic to determine who win or lose.

When i connect with a user i got a log message on my server but i got this message on my browser. "Cannot POST /".
I don't know why i got this and on my server my gameServer attributes are empty and i don't understand why data i emit from client aren't saved in my server.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i connect with a user i got a log message on my server but i got this message on my browser. "Cannot POST /". I don't know why i got this

The error `"Cannot POST /"` comes from your submit buttons in your form.  When a submit button is pressed in a form, the default behavior is to POST the form to the action URL.  Since that is not what you want, you have several ways to fix that.

First, if you have no intention of ever posting the form, then you can just remove the `<form>` tags entirely and change the buttons to regular `<button>` elements.  Then, there will be no default post just because a button was pressed.

You could also leave the HTML like it is and just prevent the default post behavior.  You would have to prevent the default behavior in each of your three click handlers like this:

```
$('#r').on('click', function(e){
    // prevent default post of form
    e.preventDefault();
    choice = "Rock"; 
    p.choice = choice;
});
```

> i don't understand why data i emit from client aren't saved in my server.

I don't see that you are actually sending any data to your server.  You are calling:

```
p.sendDataToServer();
```

which will send `p.choice` to your server.  But, this function call happens before any value has been set into either `choice` or `p.choice`.  Those values are only set LATER when the user clicks a button.  Meanwhile, you've already called `p.sendDataToServer()` before any of those buttons were ever clicked.  `.on()` creates event handlers.  These event handlers will be called sometime in the future when the user clicks a button.  Meanwhile, the rest of your code continues to run.

Similarly, your call to `p.getDataFromServer()` just installs event handlers to listen for future data that might be sent from the server.  It doesn't actually get any data at that point in time.

It looks like you need a bit of a primer on how an event-driven system works.  You set up event handlers and then, sometimes in the future, when one of those event handlers is called, you then carry out an action in the event handler callback.

Comment: thank you for your answer. You are right, i'm not used to even handling. I'll do more researches on it. :)